# Why not working this.$inertia.post('url',data).then(() => {this.loading = false});

Tags: vuejs3

[mycode[consoleerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ3jh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPQu.png)

I want loading to be false when validation fails but in console shows error undefined then().What should I do teach me.

> "runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during
> execution of native event handler at 
> at <Inertia initialPage= {component: 'Auth/Register', props: {…}, url:
> '/register', version: '', scrollRegions: Array(0), …}
> initialComponent= {name: 'Register', props: {…}, methods: {…},
> __hmrId: '52017547', data: ƒ, …} resolveComponent=fn  ... > at  warn2 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41 logError @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:216 handleError @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:208 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:160 callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime
> core.esm-bundler.js:166 invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278 Show
> 6 more frames Show lessruntime core.esm-bundler.js:221 Uncaught
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') at
> Proxy.register (Register.vue:90:59) at Register.vue:9:44 at
> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1328:12 at callWithErrorHandling
> (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158:18) at callWithAsyncErrorHandling
> (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166:17) at HTMLFormElement.invoker
> (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278:5)"

Comment: [Please do not post text, tables, or error messages as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15261914) Please [edit] your question to include the information as text.